# convert multiple text files to csv

Tags: python, csv, text

I have 3 text files in this example and would like to convert them to csv files :
I can do it for one file but for multiple files i am aseeing errors after tweaking the code multiple times :

```
    import os
    import glob3


count =1
file_name = "COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count*1) + ".txt"

def data_parser(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i,j)
    return text

while count<=3:
    for count in file_name:
        inputfile = open(file_name)
        outputfile = open("COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count*1)+ '.csv', 'w')
        reps = {'"DUT 1"':' ', ' ':' ', ' ':' ' }
        for i in range(7):  inputfile.next()

        count = count + 1
        file_name = "COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count * 1) + ".txt"
        for line in inputfile:
            outputfile.writelines(data_parser(line, reps))
    inputfile.close()
    outputfile.close()
```

In this particular case now i am running into problem because first i converted count to string and later i want to use it as integer in order to increment and check the condition. Any other thoughts or way to do it or any suggestions to improve this way ?

Comment: `for count in file_name` will iterate over the letters of `file_name` and overwrite or mask `count`.

Comment: Use a different variable name for the for loop. `count` will take on the values  of the letters in file_name.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name you are using for the count of files, `count =1` is also being used to loop through your file_name in `for count in file_name:`. Because of this, `count` will no longer be the current file number, but instead take on the characters of `file_name`.

All you need to do is use a different variable name for your for loop. For example, `for c in file_name:`

Comment: Thanks. I changed count to 'c'. Now when i create a csv file , one cell contains values which should be in 2 cells. Is there anything i can do to put the 2 values in 2 cells not one cell ?